# One Man's Dream Blocked By A Riddle

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

One morning a man woke up and received an important mail giving him a chance to go into one of the biggest server rooms in the world. Even though that may not seem much of a experience you, this individual has dreamed of being a network administrator his whole life and this could jump start his career. While admiring how he was one of many people who could go to have this experience he remembered that the email said he has a **chance** to go, not certain. The email said before he could have the experience of a life time he has to answer a question or else another individual will be chosen. The question is:

> What is the first thing you notice when you walk into a server room?

While this man wants to make network administrating as his future career he is only young and never walked into a server room ever in his life time. Could you help answer this riddle to fulfill this man's dream.

Hint 1:

> Think literal.

Hint 2:

> What is a common problem with all computers.

Hint 3:

> You would notice it imediately when you got into the room.

BIG HINT(Only use if you read all other hints and are clueless):

> It would strike one of your 5 senses in a unfavorable way.

Two people finished at the same time and I wish I can mark them off as both correct but I am not, so I gave the win to gave the closest answer first. Sorry if you didn't win

Comment: maybe [tag:lateral-thinking] ?

Comment: Good tag, let me add it

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Puzzling SE!

Comment: 'Connections' !? is the email hinting him to build good connections with his colleagues, supervisors and people who have long been in network administration ?

Comment: Is a background in IT going to be required to solve this puzzle?

Comment: No, just plain logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would notice that

> the air-conditioning is turned down to the lowest possible temperature to keep the servers cool and prevent overheating.

Comment: Not quite it, added hints if you need help

Comment: Your second answer is very close but be more specific, what would they do to prevent that

Comment: I have to say it really feels a lot more like I'm just trying to read your mind than applying any actual deductive skills here.

Comment: You got it! You would feel how cold it is to prevent overheating and airflow

Comment: Sorry if it may seem like that, but if you did walk into a sever room you would feel how cold it is before anything

Comment: @SmailBarkouch: no worries, but it seems quite a few other answers beat me to it, and without all the assistance too.

Comment: You had the closest answer first, no worries, your marked as correct

Answer (score 7):

My guess:
The first thing I *notice* is that

> It is not ice (not-ice)

Comment: I see what you did there, but sadly that is not the answer. I would put hints but I don't know how to hide them as you did with you answer.

Comment: use ">!" before. Edit my answer to check how did i write it

Comment: Added hints for help

Comment: i like this answer, because the first thing I notice is that server rooms have a tendency to overheat if you don't crank the air conditioning way up

Answer (score 3):

The new guy might feel that...

> It's Too Cold In Here

Comment: Very close, opposite

Comment: @SmailBarkouch : Correct. I remember an episode of getting a severe headache after being in server room for few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

> Of your 5 senses, you would first notice the sounds of the cooling systems if you had not already.  Then you'd feel the cold air.

Comment: You got it, basically the second answer

Answer (score 3):

You would notice the cold door handle as you open the door and walk in.
If it's automatic door you would still notice the door.

Comment: Yep, basically how cold it is but yea also how cold the door handle is